# Concatenating images in R

Tags: image, r, memory, concatenation

I'm trying to plot a large matrix (8,000 x 8,000) as a raster image in R. Unfortunately this requires too much memory for my 32-bit OS, so I'm plotting the data as two (4000 x 8000) images before recombining them.

I've looked at a lot of packages, and I've found no suitable function. I know images are imported as S4 objects with the colours stored in an array, implying that there *should* be a way to combine them, but I can't figure it out. Does anyone know how to do this in R?
Thanks

Edit:

The data is stored in 8000 csv files, with file1 corresponding to the 1st row of the matrix, file2 to the second...

example code

```
# get the name of each matrix-row file
# each file is a vector of length 8000, each filei corresponding to matrix row i 

a <- list.files()

for(i in 1:4000){

     # read the data into R, and combine it with the other rows

     matrixRow <- read.table(a[i])
     matrixToPlot <- rbind(matrixToPlot, matrixRow)   

 }


 png("test", 4000, 4000)
     rasterImage(as.raster(matrixToPlot))
 graphics.off()
 ## identical code for matrix-row 4001, 4002, ...8000
```

Comment: Can you give some sample code of what you are trying to do? Also, why don't you plot them as a vector image and then scale them later on outside of R?

Comment: I added a minimal code example.

To clarify a little, the matrix is ~1GB which R handles fine. When I call a plotting function (plot, ggplot, rasterImage) the plotting function creates large internal objects while working on the data, which stops R working. I assume the same will happen when trying to save as a vector format (.png or .svg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you **really** simplify your example code so that it runs on my machine and produces two image plots, I'll take a look. For example, construct two 10x10 matrices of random numbers.  Since you know how to read the files, this isn't part of your problem. Also, remove the `png()` and `dev.off()` - this isn't part of your problem either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following while eyeing the memory on my system monitor, and it stays below 3 Gb the whole time:

```
    A <- matrix(rnorm(8000*8000),ncol = 8000)
    print(object.size(A),units = "Mb") # 488.3 Mb
    gc() # remove wasted mem (something I don't fully understand)

    # open a plot of appropriate dimensions- scale to your case
    plot(NULL, type = "n", xlim = c(0, 8001), ylim = c(0, 8000))
    # add chunks of the image a bit at a time, removing waste memory at each chunk
    for (m in 1:4){
      for (n in 1:4){
        image(x = (m * 2000 - 2000):(m * 2000 - 1) + .5, # pixels are centered..
              y = (n * 2000 - 2000):(n * 2000 - 1) + .5, 
              t(A[(m * 2000 - 1999):(m * 2000), (n * 2000 - 1999):(n * 2000)]), 
              useRaster = TRUE, # this is key
              add = TRUE)     
        gc() # my naive guess is that this keeps wasted mem from building up
      }
    }
```

this gets the thing plotted in window about as economically as I can think of. You could do the same thing by only having parts of A at a time in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, that's a really smart way of solving the problem. It's much simpler than wrestling with S4 objects. 

I've never really got a lot of use out of the garbage collector in R though; if I define a huge object, remove it with rm(), and call gc() the memory is still full for a while. gctorture() doesn't work much better.

Thanks for the code, your method should work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try scaling down the matrix, do you really need that detail? Doing incremental rbind like that will kill performance and also that plot won't work, rasterImage needs an existing plot set up. Try asking with your real goal in mind, this is not a good way to proceed.

Comment: In this case, yes. The image I'm making is a fractal, and I'd like to view it at a close magnification without using a zoom() function. In any case I know this is a *really* stupid way of doing things; The *bigmatrix* package would be a better fit, with the performance boost of preallocation. I'm just using this method as a technical challenge, to see if I can even get it to work :)

Comment: ok, just preallocate the matrix rather than rbind and it should work fine